# How to get a text from EditText?

Tags: java, android

I make `DialogFragment` with custom `layout` and set this such way

```
AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
        .setView(layout)
        .setCancelable(true);
```

This `layout` which was set in `DialogFragment` contains `EditText`. Gist in fact that when `DialogFragment` appear, user have to enter in `EditText` your comment and then push button `send`.

It was a problem when i tried `findViewById()` , because `DialogFragment` didn't extend `Activity`, thus i try solve this issue such way :

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_note_dialog, null);
EditText etNoteFromWeb = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.etNoteFromWeb);
String response = etNoteFromWeb.getText().toString();
```

But `etNoteFromWeb.getText().toString();` everytime give me back empty line, not `null`... Actually empty line.

**What i am doing wrong?**

Here is full code of `DialogFragment` :

public class MyDialog extends DialogFragment {

```
final String LOG_TAG = "MyDialog";
private static MyDialog myDialog;
private EditText etNoteFromWeb;

int layout;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedState) {
    super.onCreate(savedState);
    Bundle args = this.getArguments();
    layout = args.getInt("layout");
}

public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
            .setView(layout)
            .setCancelable(true);

    if (layout == R.layout.activity_note_dialog) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

        View view = inflater.inflate(layout, null);

        LinearLayout llSent = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.llSent);
        LinearLayout llSkip = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.llSkip);

        llSent.setOnClickListener(listener);
        llSkip.setOnClickListener(listener);
        adb.setView(view);
    }

    return adb.create();
}

View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (layout == R.layout.activity_note_dialog) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_note_dialog, null);
            etNoteFromWeb = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etNoteFromWeb);
            String response = etNoteFromWeb.getText().toString();
//                String response = "etNoteFromWeb.getText().toString()";
            // Здесь в System.out.println ничего нет...9(( но когда раскоментирована строка 
            // выше и указываю статический текст, то все работает, проблема именно в том, 
            // что не достает текст из EditText
            System.out.println("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! " + response);
            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.llSent:
                    onClick.onDialogClickListener(response);
                    myDialog.dismiss();
                    break;
                case R.id.llSkip:
                    onClick.onDialogClickListener(null);
                    myDialog.dismiss();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
};

public void dismissDialog(final MyDialog dialog, int daleyTime) {
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                dialog.dismiss();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, daleyTime);
}

public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
    super.onDismiss(dialog);
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "MyDialog: onDismiss");
}

public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
    super.onCancel(dialog);
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "MyDialog: onCancel");
}

public static MyDialog newInstance(int layout) {
    myDialog = new MyDialog();

    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("layout", layout);
    myDialog.setArguments(args);

    return myDialog;
}


//  Этот интерфейс я реализовал для того чтоб можно было передавать данные из DialogFragment
public interface OnButtonClick {
    void onDialogClickListener(String response);
}

OnButtonClick onClick;

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);

    try {
        onClick = (OnButtonClick) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement onDialogClickListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    onClick = null;
}
}
```

Comment: don't use a System.out.prinln instead use a Log.d(TAG," Unique identifier");

Comment: @prathamkesarkar i am a rookie and i have tried some times work with `Log` and noticed that it show not each time when i expect... I will try one more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you re-inflate your layout in `onClick`, so the text is always empty.
You should move the line

```
etNoteFromWeb = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etNoteFromWeb);
```

inside `onCreateDialog` to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

you creating new view and get string from it!! its not dialog's view
use :

```
EditText etNoteFromWeb = (EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.etNoteFromWeb);
```

Comment: i don't understand extactly how i should get instanse `dialog` ? Because according my code there is no  instanse `dialog`...

Comment: you can define an object and set value on onCreateDialog before, retuen adb.create() , change it to dialog = adb.create() ; return dialog;